# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '__construct' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Tags: laravel, shopping-cart

I have this problem. When I click on add to cart button there is an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '__construct' (T_STRING),
>   expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

I'm new in Laravel and I really have no idea what I have to do,

This is my code on button add to Cart:

```
<a href="{{route('get.addToCart',[$product->id])}}" class="cart-btn">Add to cart</a>
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('add-to-cart/{id}', 'WebController@addToCart')->name('get.addToCart');
```

This I have in webcontroller:

```
public function addToCart(Request $request, $id){
   $product = Product::find($id);
   $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
   $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
   $cart->add($product,$product->id);
   $request->session()->put('cart',$cart);
   dd($request->session()->get('cart'));
   return redirect()->route(get.product);
}
```

And this is my `cart.php`

```
<?php
namespace App;
class Cart{
   public $items=null;
   public __construct($oldCart){
      if($oldCart){
        this->$items=$oldCart->items;
      }
   }
   public function add($item,$id){
      $storedItem= ['name'=>$item];
      if(this-> $items)
      { 
         if(array_key_exists($id, this->$items)){
           $storedItem=this->$items[$id];
         }
      }
      this->$items[$id]=$storedItem;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `__construct` needs to have the word `function` in front of it, or better yet `public function`

Change the line to:

```
public function __construct($oldCart)
```

Read out here: [Line no 8](https://github.com/mystikraz/shopping-cart/blob/master/Desktop/shopping-cart/app/Http/Controllers/Cart.php#L8)

Comment: Thanks can you help me with another problem?

Comment: @AngelikaBeňová yes, I will try my best

Comment: You can see this problem in comment

Comment: There is still the problem

Undefined index: item (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\shoppingCart.blade.php)

Comment: undefined index occurs due to undefined variables.

Answer (score 1):

there is missing **function** keyword before __construct

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Cart{
    public $items=null;
    public function __construct($oldCart){
        if($oldCart){
            $this->items=$oldCart->items;
        }
    }

    public function add($item,$id){
        $storedItem= ['name'=>$item];
        if($this->items)
            {
                if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
                     $storedItem=$this->items[$id];
                }
            }
        $this->items[$id]=$storedItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have another problem can you help me?
You can see it in comment

Answer (score 0):

```
this->$items[$id]=$storedItem;
```

[See](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php), this is a keyword and is $this, and when accessing variables through this no need to do the $ sign on the accessed variable (in this case items), so it should always be:

```
$this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
```

And please indent and organise your code better, this is pretty chaotic and there is probably more than one error.

Comment: Thanks I have another problem you can see it in comments

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<?php
namespace App;
class Cart{
public $items=null;
public function __construct($oldCart){
    if($oldCart){
        this->$items=$oldCart->items;
    }
}
public function add($item,$id){
    $storedItem= ['name'=>$item];
    if(this-> $items)
        {if(array_key_exists($id, this->$items)){
            $storedItem=this->$items[$id];
        }
        }
        this->$items[$id]=$storedItem;
}
}
```