# I have problem with my code "UNDEFINED INDEX"

Tags: laravel, indexing, undefined

There is link to my previous problem where is code,maybe it helps you 
[Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '__construct' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881476/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-construct-t-string-expecting-functi/53883005#53883005)

this is problem i get

Undefined index: item (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\shoppingCart.blade.php)
this error is there `<strong><?php echo e($product['item']['name']); ?></strong>`

this is my route

```
Route::get('shoppingCart', 'WebController@shoppingCart')->name('get.shoppingCart');
```

this is in my webcontroller

```
public function shoppingCart(){
  if(!Session::has('cart')){
    return view('shoppingCart');
  }
  $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
  $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
  return view('shoppingCart',['products'=>$cart->items]);
}
```

this is link for cart

```
<li><a href="{{ route('get.shoppingCart') }}">CART  <span class="badge">{{Session::has('cart') ? '!' : ''}}</span></a></li>
```

And this is my code for shoppingCart

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
@if(Session::has('cart'))
    <div>
        <div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach($products as $product)
                <li class="list-group-item"></li>
                <strong>{{$product['item']['name']}}</strong>
                <li><a href="#">Odstrániť</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

@else
<div>
    <h2>V košíku nemáš žiadne položky!!!</h2>
</div>
@endif

@endsection
```

Comment: Hello, you should include all the details necessary to answer you, as this is another question. At least the code line where the error happens, and the full error too (which index is undefined?)

Comment: @Angelika Beňová: can't understand your question

Comment: @AngelikaBeňová If you get a new error, then ask the question according to the new error. you can edit your question, and put proper all details according to error then we can easily help you

Comment: thanks I edit this question

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can check if you have data or not on $cart->items while writing dd($cart->items); on the your function . Follow my comments .

```
public function shoppingCart(){
  if(!Session::has('cart')){
    return view('shoppingCart');
  }
  $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
  $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

 //dd($cart->items) /*uncomment this and check if you have data or not if you have no then problem is  */
  return view('shoppingCart',['products'=>$cart->items]); /* on the other if you have data dont forget those line and look at my comment on blade.php */
}
```

Your blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
@if(Session::has('cart'))
    <div>
        <div>
            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach($products as $product)
                <li class="list-group-item"></li>
                <strong>{{$product['item']['name']}}</strong>



<!--Look at here you remembe you were add products writing `['products'=>$cart->items]` then you be care calling your datas first you be relay on your codes you are working array (it seems you are working with objects then you need to call it $products->item->name Secondly you remember on the function you were add your data `['products'=>$cart->items]` like this if there is no child items object on $cart->items then you need to call it like 

        foreach($products as $product))
        {
         echo $product->name; //if it is array then echo $product['name'];
        }

    -->
                    <li><a href="#">Odstrániť</a></li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    @else
    <div>
        <h2>V košíku nemáš žiadne položky!!!</h2>
    </div>
    @endif

    @endsection
```